# Refresh Sub Tab In Service Console

Tags: javascript, service-cloud-console, console

This is so frustrating, I can't even make Salesforce sample examples work!

My goal is to create a button that would refresh the current sub tab when clicked.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function testRefreshSubtabById() {
        sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(subtabId);
      }
        var subtabId = function subtabId(result){
          sforce.console.refreshSubtabById(result.id, true, refreshSuccess);
      }

    var refreshSuccess = function refreshSuccess(result) {
        //Report whether refreshing the subtab was successful
        if (result.success == true) {
            alert('Subtab refreshed successfully');
        } else {
            alert('Subtab did not refresh');
        }
    };
```

[Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_refreshsubtabbyid.htm)

Comment: Where is your button code? It would be better if you can include more of your page.

Comment: <a HREF="#" onClick="testRefreshSubtabById();return false">Click here to refresh this tab</a>

Comment: Did you include this `<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/22.0/integration.js"/>` in your page?

Comment: Yes, <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/38.0/integration.js"/>